# Overflow : scroll is ignored

Tags: css, overflow

So basically, I have this structure (sample) :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti odio pariatur numquam aspernatur ex iste praesentium. Aliquid quo voluptas eaque sequi autem voluptatem alias ullam provident tempora adipisci optio error!
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui odit esse assumenda eligendi obcaecati quas sapiente voluptatum a enim quam officia aliquid exercitationem earum at sint harum ullam nostrum distinctio! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui odit esse assumenda eligendi obcaecati quas sapiente voluptatum a enim quam officia aliquid exercitationem earum at sint harum ullam nostrum distinctio!
    </div>
</div>
```

And this stylesheet :

```
.container {
    height: 100px;
}
.header {
    background-color: blue;
}
.content {
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I would like to apply an `overflow: auto` on the `.content` as its content overflows the container height, however this simply does not work (see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q26cL/2/)). I can apply an `overflow: auto` to `.container` and it will work but I don't want to apply the scroll on the `.header` element.

Furthermore, the `.header` height may change, so I can't set a fixed height to `.content`.

Any idea/suggestion ?
Thanks :)

EDIT : To clarify, I set a height to the container, I cant set a height to neither `.header` (which may change but won't be bigger than `.container`) nor `.content` (which may overlap the `.container` height because of `.header`)

Comment: "but I don't want to apply the scroll on the `.header` element" I'm confused because your CSS shows you doing exactly that.

Comment: @crush My CSS applies a height to `.container`, not to `.header`.

Comment: I/You didn't say anything about height in the quote.

Comment: @crush Well, the scroll depends quite heavily on the height, right?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if you want the scroll on the header element or not. You said you don't want the scroll on the header element, yet your CSS has scroll set on the header element. I'm done here. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your time then ! However I have no idea where you see that my header has a scroll : `.header { background-color: blue; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in CSS unfortunately, but with little javascript it will work.

```
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var header = document.querySelector(".header");
var content = document.querySelector(".content");

content.style.height = (container.offsetHeight - header.offsetHeight) + "px";
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently using this workaround too but would have preferred a CSS trick :(

Comment: No native CSS way found so I rolled back to a js version instead, like this one.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/q26cL/3/

It's because you don't have a height. So the div expands accordingly to the content.

I set a height of `120px for .content` and it works now.

```
.content {
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Sadly as I stated at the end of my question: "Furthermore, the .header height may change, so I can't set a fixed height to .content."

Comment: @simon I can get it to work obviously with % height too, but yea, I don't believe without specifying a height you can do this with just css